# How to configure org-mode in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I did not know where to ask that question, so I am asking here.

I have trouble onfiguring org-mode (specficly org capture) in spacemacs.

In my .spacemacs file (in the fucntion `dotspacemacs/user-init`) I have added the following code :

```
(setq org-default-notes-file "~/Desktop/notes2.org")

 (setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
                '((org :variables org-projectile-file "~/Desktop/TODOs.org")))
```

But whene I press SPC a o c saves the "TODO" in `~/notes.org` file and not in `~/Desktop/notes2.org`.

Also it throws the following error message :

```
Error (use-package): org-projectile/:config: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-projectile:per-repo
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not your fault. It's a bug for which the fix has not been merged into master for a very long time (scroll to the buttom to see how people still confirm having the same problem):

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9374

Comment: Side note: "No-one uses master branch of spacemacs. Go for the develop branch!"

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is use the develop branch of spacemacs. The bug is fixed and merged there, and the release is not that ¨unstable" as it may sound.